# Mapping data (from getJSON response) in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have a problem with parsing data to my chart.
For sure, this should be included in an automatic process I use getJSON and don't want to use ajax, so I have:

```js
$.getJSON('file.json').done( function (results) {  

        var labels = [];
        var data = [];

        var labels = results.map(function (item) {
            return item.updatedLaels
        });

        var data = results.map(function (item) {
            return item.updatedData;
        });

        console.log(labels)
        console.log(data)
    });
```

So of course labels and data are logged to console in a proper way e.g.:

```js
(5) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

But how to use it in this part:

```js
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Example',
                data: data,
                borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            }]
        },
    });
```

Because index.html generates an empty chart without data. How to map labels and data in the proper way?

Comment: Firstly `$.getJSON` is an `async` call and `labels` and `data` are local variables. Those variables are `undefined` out of the scope of your `callback function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`labels` and `data` variables are `undefined` outside of your `$.getJSON`'s `done` `callback` function.

You can call a function in `done` i.e `createChart(labels, data)` or can bring you chart code inside `done`

```
$.getJSON('file.json').done( function (results) {  

        var labels = [];
        var data = [];

        var labels = results.map(function (item) {
            return item.updatedLabels
        });

        var data = results.map(function (item) {
            return item.updatedData;
        });

        // Create chart
        createChart(labels, data);

});
```

```
function createChart(labels, data) {
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Example',
                data: data,
                borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            }]
        },
    });

}
```